# How would one be able to randomly print 10 strings with 'n' letters, but each string has the same first letter

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, random

I am trying to make a code that will put random inputs until it finds the correct word inputted by the user.  So far, I have the following: (I am really new to coding).

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomeWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Words");
        String words = scanner1.nextLine();
        int letters = words.length();
    
        for(int i1 = 1; i1 > 0; i1++) {
            if(words.contains(" ")) {
                String[] alpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < letters; i3++) {
                    sb.append(alpha[(int)(Math.random()*27)]);
                }
            
                String finall = sb.toString();
            
                if(!finall.equals(words)) {
                    System.out.println(finall);
                }
            
                if(finall.equals(words)) {
                    System.out.println(finall);
                    System.out.println(i1);
                    System.out.println("it took " +i1 + " tries to randomly find the word.");
                    System.out.println("It should have taken " +Math.pow((int) 27, letters) +" times, statistacally");
                
                    System.out.println("The difference of statistically, and with the simulation is " +(int)Math.abs((int)i1 - (int)Math.pow(27, letters)));
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
                            
            if(!words.contains(" ")){
                String[] alpha1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("");
                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < letters; i2++) {
                    sb1.append(alpha1[(int)(Math.random()*26)]);
                }
                String finall1 = sb1.toString();
                
                if(!finall1.equals(words))
                    System.out.println(finall1);
                
                if(finall1.equals(words)) {
                    System.out.println(finall1);
                    System.out.println(i1);
                    System.out.println("it took " +i1 + " tries to randomly find the word.");
                    System.out.println("It should have taken " +Math.pow((int) 26, letters) +" times, statistacally");
                    
                    System.out.println("The difference of statistically, and with the simulation is " +Math.abs((int)i1 - (int)Math.pow(26, letters)));
                    System.exit(0);
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is one difficulty that I can't get past.  I would like to have this code be more efficient.  Once it randomly runs the first string, I would like it to save the correct letters.  The next time it prints a string, I would like the letters to be in the same spot.
EX: The word is HELLO.     the first string the computer inputs is fstli.  As you can see, the second to last letter matches up.  In the next string the code prints, I would like to have that l be in the same spot.  If the next word is Hplli, I would like the H, L, and L to stay in the correct spot.

Thank You

Comment: I teach myself to code, so this is probably really not efficient by the way!

Comment: You have to consider Upper Case characters as well **unless** you ignore letter case in your code during character comparisons for equality. Remove punctuation, special characters, or numerical digits if not desired in User's input. You don't need the two `if` statements: `if(finall.equals(words)) {` and `if(!finall.equals(words)) {`. If it can find a whitespace it just wont process it anyways. No sense duplicating code. Don't declare and initialize `alpha` in each iteration of the `for` loop, do that once before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the random `String` using two different methods.  The first method creates the initial random `String`.  The second method compares the input words with the previous random `String`.

Here's a test I ran that shows the guesses.  Use a two or three letter word or else you'll generate a long output.

```
The computer will randomly guess your words.
Enter one or more words.  Just press enter to quit.
but
Guess 1 is: ist
Guess 2 is: wgt
Guess 3 is: v t
Guess 4 is: cnt
Guess 5 is: eut
Guess 6 is: nut
Guess 7 is: eut
Guess 8 is:  ut
Guess 9 is: gut
Guess 10 is: sut
Guess 11 is: tut
Guess 12 is: eut
Guess 13 is: hut
Guess 14 is:  ut
Guess 15 is: aut
Guess 16 is: mut
Guess 17 is: aut
Guess 18 is: uut
Guess 19 is: wut
Guess 20 is: tut
Guess 21 is: yut
Guess 22 is: gut
Guess 23 is: but
The computer will randomly guess your words.
Enter one or more words.  Just press enter to quit.
```

I wrote this code one method at a time.  By breaking the code up into methods, I could test each method individually.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomWords rw = new RandomWords();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        rw.processWords(scanner);
        scanner.close();
    }
    
    private Random random;
    
    public void processWords(Scanner scanner) {
        this.random = new Random();
        String line;
        do {
            System.out.println("The computer will randomly guess your words.");
            System.out.println("Enter one or more words.  Just press enter to quit.");
            line = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                processGuesses(line);
            }
        } while (!line.isEmpty());
    }
    
    private void processGuesses(String line) {
        int count = 0;
        String randomString = generateRandomString(line);
        
        while (!randomString.equals(line)) {
            System.out.println("Guess " + ++count + " is: " + randomString);
            if (!randomString.equals(line)) {
                randomString = generateRandomString(line, randomString);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Guess " + ++count + " is: " + randomString);
    }
    
    private String generateRandomString(String line, String randomString) {
        char[] alphabet = generateAlphabet();
        String output = "";
        
        char[] lineCharacters = line.toCharArray();
        char[] randomCharacters = randomString.toCharArray();
        
        for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index++) {
            if (lineCharacters[index] == randomCharacters[index]) {
                output += lineCharacters[index];
            } else {
                int sub = random.nextInt(alphabet.length);
                output += alphabet[sub];
            }
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
    private String generateRandomString(String line) {
        char[] alphabet = generateAlphabet();
        String output = "";
        
        for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index++) {
            int sub = random.nextInt(alphabet.length);
            output += alphabet[sub];
        }
        
        return output;
    }

    private char[] generateAlphabet() {
        return " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    }

}
```